# Arcgis: authentification via JS application

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I am writing a program using JavaScript, which connects to a local ArcGIS server through ArcGIS REST API and loads the maps.

The URL to get service is

```
let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
let url = "http://domain/arcgis/rest/services/" + serviceName +"/MapServer/" + layer_id +  "/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&outFields=*";
```

I can get the token through the API. The problem is, I can't set it in cookies, as the browser rejects programmatically writing another domain.

May someone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `&token=abcd1234` to your url, so you get :

```
let token = 'abcd1234';
let url = `http://domain/arcgis/rest/services/${serviceName}/MapServer/${layer_id}/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&outFields=*&token=${token}`;
```